# GnuPG installed, but "command not found" from gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, task, gnupg

I've installed `gpg` using `brew` (macOS) with `brew install gnupg gnupg2` and it works okay. I can use it or just check `gpg --version` or whatever.

> MacMini:~ boost$ gpg --version
>   gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.22
>   libgcrypt 1.8.0

The problem is that when I run it from the gradle task in Android Studio, it doesn't work anymore: `gpg` command is not found anymore.

The task is (nothing special actually):

```
task decryptSigningProperties(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'gpg', '--passphrase-file', file(project.property("passPhraseFile")), '-o', 'signing.properties', '-d', 'signing.properties.enc'
}
```

And I receive an error in the Jenkins build log:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:decryptSigningProperties'.
>     A problem occurred starting process 'command 'gpg''

At the same time, I can do it manually, navigate to the specific directory and run:

```
gpg -o signing.properties -d signing.properties.enc
```

Then, everything works fine (it prompts me for pass and do the decryption).

So why is the command `gpg` unrecognized in the task but I can run in from the terminal? Does anyone have some experience with kind of issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like your `$PATH` variable is not the same when using Gradle and your normal command line. Find out where GnuPG is installed by running `which gpg` (will likely be `/usr/local/bin/gpg` as you're using `brew`). Either configure the `$PATH` variable in your Gradle task to include `/usr/local/bin` (or whatever the path determined by `which gpg` is), or call GnuPG using the full absolut path.